# Must not with and in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 4 fields in an elastic search schema.

```
date
status
type
createdAt
```

Now, I need to fetch all the rows where

```
date=today
status = "confirmed" 
and where type is not equals to "def"
```

However, it is ok if

```
type=def exists
```

but only when the field `createdAt` is not equals to `today`.

My current query looks like this:

```
{
    must: [
        { "bool":
            {
                "must": [
                    {"term": {"date": 'now/d'}},
                    {"term": {"status": 'confirmed'}},
                ]
          }
        }
    ],
    mustNot: [
        {"match": {'createdAt': 'now/d'}},
        {"match":{"type": "def"}}
    ]
}
```

The rows where type is not equals to "`def`" are fetched.
However, if a row has the `type=def AND createdAT any date but today`, then the row doesn't show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query should work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
          { "term": {"date": "now/d" } },
          { "term": {"status": "confirmed" } }
       ],
       "must_not": {
         "bool": {
           "must": [
              { "match": { "createdAt": "now/d" } },
              { "match": { "type": "def" } }
           ]
         }
       }
    }
  } 
}
```

I believe the reason that your version is not working is that every query in the must_not must not match.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html#_controlling_precision

> All the must clauses must match, and all the must_not clauses must not match, but how many should clauses should match? By default, none of the should clauses are required to match, with one exception: if there are no must clauses, then at least one should clause must match.

Comment: Thank you. But I guess you didn't try it? I get a malformed exception.

Comment: I tried it without exception in the Kibana console. Could you still get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a setup like this:

```
PUT twitter
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a sample doc like this (adjust values to test the query):

```
post twitter/_doc/1
{
 "date": 1536562800000, //start of TODAY September 10, 2018 in UTC
 "createdAt": 1536562799999,
 "status": "confirmed",
 "type": "def"
}
```

the following query should work:

```
get twitter/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "now/d",
                  "lte": "now/d"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "status": "confirmed"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "range": {
                "createdAt": {
                  "gte": "now/d",
                  "lte": "now/d"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "def"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a filtered query which i think for this scenario is better because it doesn't calculate the score. If you do want to calculate the score, just remove the bool and the filter from the top.